# how to get data from each side of the hyperplane after developing a SVM model in R

Tags: r, svm

I developed a SVM model for a classification problem

```
    install.packages('e1071')
    library(e1071)
    fit_7 = svm(formula = Heatwave ~ .,data = training_set_7,type = 'C-classification',kernel = 'linear')
```

My question is- how do I get two dataset (1st dataset is from one side of hyperplane; and 2nd dataset is form another side of hyperplane) from this fit_SVM model? All I want two datasets that included observations from above and under the hyperplane.

Thanks in advance

I tried following:

```
    install.packages('e1071')
    library(e1071)
    fit_7 = svm(formula = Heatwave ~ .,data = training_set_7,type = 'C-classification',kernel = 'linear')
```

I am expecting to create two csv files that includes observations from above and under the hyperplane